# How do you call a containers class method from a contained object?

Tags: python, oop

Trying to write a program which mimics a school. I have two classes, one for a class (as lesson) and one for a student. In the class object there is an array which contains instances of the student object - because the students are in a class.

A student can leave a class (I have a method for this), but this doesn't mean they leave the subject (they may switch classes for example). However, it is also feasible that the student will drop a subject, which means they also leave the class. I want to create a method in the student class called dropSubject which then calls the removeStudent method from the containing class object.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: You need to keep track of this relationship yourself in your classes state.  Objects keep no information about what is referencing them. In any case, there are many possible ways to do this, but it depends on how you are structuring things exactly